# Not getting the Dropdown's data in Django view

Tags: python, django, drop-down-menu

I was trying to get the item selected in the Dropdown menu of the form. But i can't access the selected item. So to check, whether the data is available in views.py i used messages.error().But it shows None like [image: this]
Here is the form:

```
    <form method="post" name="deleteitemform" id="deleteitemform" style="padding-bottom:50px; padding-top:10px;">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id='prepandID'>Item Name :</span>
                    <select class="form-control" id="delete-item-select" name='delete_select'>
                        {% for item in items %}
                        <option value="{{item.item_name}}">{{item.item_name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary col col-md-2 col-md-offset-5" style="margin-top:10px;" name='deletebutton' type="submit">Delete</button>
     </form>
```

And in views.py:

```
    if 'deletebutton' in request.POST:
            selected_item = request.POST.get("detele_select", None)
            # to_be_deleted = Item.objects.filter(item_name=selected_item)
            # to_be_deleted.delete()


            messages.error(request, str(selected_item))
            return redirect('/restaurant/updateitems')

        else:
            return redirect("/")
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help on this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views you use `detele_select` instead of `delete_select` specified in your form.

By the way, it is easier and more convenient to use Django forms. It does a lot of work instead of you.

Comment: That's much embarrassing.
Thanks.

Comment: We all make mistakes. I'm glad I was able to help